# Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke

Tags: c#, wpf

Im getting the following error when using the following code:
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => actualServer.SetServerData(serverData));
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var source = new List<ServerProperty>
        {
            new ServerProperty("connectionstring1", "server1"),
            new ServerProperty("connectionstring2", "server2"),
            new ServerProperty("connectionstring3", "server3"),
            new ServerProperty("connectionstring4", "server4"),
        };

        DataContext = source;
        _timer = new Timer((t) =>
        {
            foreach (var serverProperty in source)
            {
                ServerProperty server = serverProperty;
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
                {
                    var serverData = ServerDataCalculator.GetServerData(server.ConnectionString);
                    var actualServer = (ServerProperty)o;
                    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => actualServer.SetServerData(serverData));

                }, server);
            }
        }, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no overload taking a delegate. Try with:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(
     new Action(() => actualServer.SetServerData(serverData)));
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a complete list of the `Invoke` overloads

Comment: @dice Since it worked for you, you may want to mark this response as an 'Answer` so other users (like myself) can get attention.